# Use vue-html-editor in vue-component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

So I want to use the [vue-html-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-editor) inside a vue-component for my page but it isn't working. I'm new to vue and vue components so I think this should be an easy task but somehow I'm stumbling to get it right.

My component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <vue-html-editor name="html-editor" :model.sync="text"></vue-html-editor>
    <div style="margin-top:40px">
      <div> The HTML contents are as follows:</div>
      <hr>
      <div>{{ text }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Edit',
    components: {
      "vue-html-editor": require("vue-html-editor")
    },
    data() {
      return {
        text: 'Start writing your notes here...'
      }
    }
  }

</script>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

And the console error message:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <VueHtmlEditor>
       <Edit> at src/components/Edit.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

I already installed the vue-html-editor but I think I haven't properly loaded the editor.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, all that comes to mind is: did you `npm install vue-html-editor`?

Comment: Yes I did install vue-html-editor like mentioned in the setup steps from the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the vue-html-editor github commits page, I saw the last update was from 2 years ago.. 
The vue-html-editor is compatible for Vue 1.0 but maybe it's not for the newest version.
However, if you keep having issues with the vue-html-editor, maybe it's worth to try the vue-quill-editor. I found that it is easy to implement and the documentation is really good.

https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also saw that the vue-html-editor seems to be outdated but haven't found a good looking alternative. Your suggestion is working fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: Does quill finally support line breaks / soft breaks? Like Shift + Enter or something? I switched to tinymces official vue component.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned on the requirements that besides Node.js you need another library called summernote.

Install it using npm or yarn

https://www.npmjs.com/package/summernote

and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: This sadly didn't help. I also thought that summernote was automatically installed because it is listed as a required component for the editor. Anyway I installed it extra using npm without any change.